# How to change the color of the Toolbar text programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

My toolbar title needs to be able to change color depending on button click. For example, the default color for the toolbar title is white, but if I press a button, I want it to change to red for example.

I tried using the following:

```
SpannableString title;
title.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.argb(1, 255, 64, 129)), 0, remainingTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

But for some reason the color just does not want to change. It used to work with actionbar, but for some reason this same method does not work with toolbar.

Answer (score 8):

You can use something like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Hello");
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.RED);//for red colored toolbar title
```

Answer (score 3):

`Toolbar` can change its text color. So, just call `Toolbar.setTitleTextColor(int color)`.

If you want to span a text, you need to call `TextView.setText(SpannableString)`. Here is an example:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers"); 
//Handle with your Span here. Like change color of part text, bold or italic part text, add hypertext and something like that.
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
toolbar.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Comment: What if I wanted to only change a portion of the titles color? Say only a couple letters out of the entire title. I should have been more specific, that's what I want to do.

Comment: I want to span my toolbar title though, not a textview. Also, in my post I tried to use SpannableString but it didn't seem to affect the color of my title. Thanks for sticking with me though

Answer (score 3):

Using the **v7 appcompat library** you can call `setTitleTextColor()` on the Toolbar

```
if (actionBarToolbar != null)
    actionBarToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.RED);
```

---

**couple letters out of the entire title :**

```
getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>YourColorText</font>") + "tittle");
```

Comment: What if I wanted to only change a portion of the titles color? Say only a couple letters out of the entire title. I should have been more specific, that's what I want to do

Comment: to change color of text in your tittle will  be tricky. you might need to add subtittle and change its color for that check this http://www.coderzheaven.com/2014/10/09/change-title-subtitle-text-color-actionbar-android/